# Group By & Sum Multiple Columns

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I have the following sql query and I would like to convert it into a lambda expression:

```
SELECT TOP 10 SUM(Quantity * Price) AS Quantity, Category 
FROM InvoiceItem 
WHERE Unit = 'Hour' 
GROUP BY Category 
ORDER BY Quantity DESC
```

I have tried many things but I don't understand what is wrong with this:

```
var data = _db.InvoiceItem.Where(where => where.Unit == "Hour")
                          .GroupBy(group => new { group.Category })
                          .Select(group => new
                          {
                              Category = group.Key.Category,
                              Quantity = group.Sum(s => s.Quantity * s.Price)
                          })               
                          .OrderByDescending(ob => ob.Quantity)
                          .Take(10);
```

Unfortunately I keep getting the following error:

> Message = "Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values."

Here is my model:

```
namespace Accounts.Models
{

    public enum UnitList
    {
        Hour, Each, Km, Bag
    }

    public class InvoiceItem
    {

        public InvoiceItem()
        {
            Price = 0;
            Quantity = 1;          
            Unit = UnitList.Each.ToString();
            Display = false;
        }

        [Key]
        public int InvoiceItemID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int InvoiceID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int PersonID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid UserID { get; set; }

        [Required]        
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        //[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Category { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Aircraft { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(200)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Unit { get; set; }     

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = false, DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DefaultValue(1)]
        public decimal? Quantity { get; set; }

        [UIHint("Boolean")]
        public Boolean Display { get; set; }

        public virtual Invoice Invoice { get; set; }

        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }        
    } 


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you are getting data where `Category` is `null`. So you need to add extra condition in `Where`. Also, you can slightly simplify `GroupBy`:

```
_db.InvoiceItem.Where(i => i.Unit == "Hour" && i.Category != null)
                      .GroupBy(i => i.Category)
                      .Select(i => new
                      {
                          Category = i.Key.Category,
                          Quantity = i.Sum(s => s.Quantity * s.Price)
                      })               
                      .OrderByDescending(i => i.Quantity)
                      .Take(10);
```

Comment: I copy and pasted your exact code, I get the following error: `'string' does not contain a definition for 'Category' and no accessible extension method 'Category' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` The `i.Key.Category` part is underlined in red.

Comment: OK I fixed the first string error by changing to `Category = i.Key,`.  However I am still getting the null value error.  It seems to be related to the multiplication part.  If I just use s.Quantity or s.Price it works,  but it fails when the two are multiplied.   Any ideas?

Comment: @Reafidy Try `(s.Quantity ?? 0) * (s.Price ?? 0)`

Comment: I get the following compile error on s.price only: `Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'int'`

Comment: Ok so this works `Quantity = i.Sum(s => s.Price)` but this does not `Quantity = i.Sum(s => s.Price * 1)`  That seems very odd.  Why does multiplying by one produce a null value error?

Comment: @Reafidy Could you posst data your query uses?

Comment: I posted my model, does that help?  The database is huge.

Comment: @Reafidy maybe `s.Quantity.Value * s.Price`

Comment: Unfortunately not, I still get the same error.  Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: @Reafidy Well, it would be better to see your actual data, maybe you have null values in your data - that may be causing this error.

Comment: I just ran the following query on my database for category, price, quantity `SELECT  * FROM InvoiceItem WHERE Category Is Null`  there were no rows returned.  Do you have a suggestion how I can show you the data?

Comment: @Reafidy What about `Pirce` and `Quantity` fields? Check if any of these are `null`

Comment: Sorry that's what I meant, I ran that query on all three fields, no nulls anywhere.

Comment: It doesnt like the multiplication part.  `Quantity = i.Sum(s => s.Price)` works fine and I get an output, but this causes a null error:  `Quantity = i.Sum(s => s.Price * 1)`

Comment: For some reason when using a multiplier inside the lambda sum expression it checks the entire database fields for nulls.   Turns out my model did not match my database.  My description field did not allow nulls but my database did allow nulls.  And there were some rows with nulls in the description.  This caused the error, but only when using multiplication.   Thanks for your help.